# Запрет подключения js скрипта на сайте по ip-адресу хостинга

Tags: php, javascript, ip

Наткнулся на сайте на скрипт, который подключается в самом конце страницы с другого сайта.
Естественно, я его не подключал.

Как мне запретить подключение чего либо на сайт, зная ip хоста откуда подключается это самое что-либо?

P.S. Скрипт читает и создает куки у пользователей

Comment: Вам не об этом нужно думать, а о том что вас взломали ;)

Comment: Логи говорят об обратном. Кроме моего ip к FTP аккаунту ни кто не обращался

Comment: Значит задайте вопрос своему хостеру, зачем они подключили вам левый скрипт. P.S. Логи вам могут ни чего не показать, если сломали не вас, а соседний сайт на том же сервере.

Comment: @Артем, а еще вас могут взломать с вашего же IP (например через троян или backdoor). Либо, если провайдер дает IP на _подсеть_, то с одного из компьютеров подсети.

Comment: @Артем, добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос код, который вам дописали без вашего ведома.

Comment: http://bstu32.ru/html/js/choose-bryansk.js

Comment: Разобрались, ребят
Хостинг арендуем у одной веб-студии.
Директор этой веб-студии разрешил студентам разместить на ВСЕХ сайтах этот код.

Comment: Но вопрос остается тот же, могу я запретить по ip подключать скрипты на мой сайт?

Comment: @Артем, да не сам скрипт-то, а как он у вас в файлах подключен.

Answer (score 1):

ваш сайт формирует и отдаёт браузеру посетителя *html-документ*.

в нём (обычно) упомянуто множество *url-ов*.

упоминания этих *url-ов* — это не просьба и (тем более) не приказ браузеру. это **рекомендация**: вот по этому *url-у* вы можете получить картинку, скрипт, ещё один *html-файл* и т.д. и т.п.

следовать ли **вашим** рекомендациям, или игнорировать их, браузер клиента решает **самостоятельно** (на основании своих настроек и заложенной разработчиками браузера логики).

и уж тем более вы не можете **запретить** браузеру клиента воспользоваться *вашими же рекомендациями*.